# class attribute usage in epub

Tags: language-agnostic

For websites, typically viewed on the browser, we can use a space separated list of classes `class="class1 class2 class3"`. On my tests with epub it seems that I can also use a space separated list. However, I am not quiet sure if this is well supported for most epub readers. Is it safe to use this technique for epub? Anyone tested it on some epub readers?

Please note: I only tested it on ADE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested that on most of the major readers on the market: nook, nook color, Kobo Arc, Kobo Mini, various Android reading systems, even my old 1st gen Sony Reader, and it works fine.

Comment: Great, I've been searching the web for answers but haven't found one. Its best if someone could put up an epub compatibility chart. I was planning to do so but I just don't have the resources.

Comment: The Book Industry Study Group (BISG) has a very useful support grid that details the capabilities of a lot of the reading systems out there. Check it out: http://www.bisg.org/publications/product.php?p=26&c=437